# Is the normalised Kauffman bracket more powerful than the Kauffman bracket?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, knot-theory

The [Kauffman bracket polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_polynomial) for a knot diagram $D$ is a Laurent polynomial $\langle D \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}[A, A^{-1}]$. Although it is invariant under Reidemeister moves of type II and III, performing a type I move on $D$ will change $\langle D \rangle$ by a factor of $-A^{\pm 3}$. So $\langle D \rangle$ is not a knot invariant.

One solution to this is to define a normalised bracket polynomial:
$$ X(D) = (-A^3)^{-w(D)} \langle D \rangle \quad \textrm{where $w(D)$ is the writhe of $D$}. $$
This is invariant under type I moves too and so is a knot invariant (it also turns out to be a reparametrisation of the Jones polynomial).

However an alternate solution is to simply say that the bracket polynomial is only defined up to multiplication by a power of $-A^3$. Although this appears to be disregarding some information, it is still possible to use it to show that many pairs of knots are distinct. For example, as
$$ A^{16} - A^{12} - A^4 \neq (-A^3)^k \times 1 \quad \textrm{for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$} $$
we can still conclude that the trefoil is not equal to the unknot. However, is this actually a weaker knot invariant? That is

> > > Are there two distinct knots which the normalised bracket polynomial can tell apart but which the Kauffman bracket polynomial cannot?

I've checked all the knots listed on [KnotInfo](http://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/) (which covers prime knots up to 12 crossings) and found no such pair.

It is also worth noting however that if we allow ourselves to work with oriented links then: if we reverse the orientation of one component $k$ of an oriented link diagram $D$ to obtain a new diagram $D'$ then
$$ \langle D' \rangle = A^{12 \lambda} \langle D \rangle \quad \textrm{where $\lambda = \textrm{linknum}(k, D - k)$.} $$
Hence, for example, the normalised bracket polynomial can distinguish between the compatibly and incompatibly oriented Hopf links (L2a1{0} and L2a1{1}) but the bracket polynomial cannot.

Comment: Rather than say that the Kauffman bracket is not a knot invariant, I would say that it is an invariant of framed knots.  (Which, in my biased opinion, is nicer/better than being an invariant of unframed knots.)